# Cline multi-page table

Tags: tables, cline

I have a single table over more pages and when I use \cline at the end of the last row in a page, the line appears only at the end of the page but not in the begin of the new page at the first row of the table.

With \hline I have the effect that I want but the line pass through all the columns.

I give an example:

[image]

Any suggestion?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{ltablex}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
    \newcolumntype{K}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash \columncolor{blue!10}}m{3cm}}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
%\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=0.8333\hsize}K|
                              >{\hsize=0.4167\hsize}L|
                              >{\hsize=1.0000\hsize}L|
                              >{\hsize=0.8333\hsize}L|}

\hline
\rowcolor{gray!50}\textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d}\\
\rowcolor{lightgray}   &   &   &   \\
\rowcolor{lightgray}   &   &   &   \\
\hline
& & & \\
\textbf{Bla bla bla}\par 
\emph{jjjjj}
 & r & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut elit ac ipsum placerat scelerisque eget id justo. Ut cursus viverra neque, in porta justo facilisis sit amet. Donec vitae libero a diam lobortis ultrices. Vestibulum metus urna, pharetra et cursus quis, eleifend ut dui. Phasellus pellentesque, quam et hendrerit. & d \\
 &    &   & \\
\cline{2-4}
 & r& Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut elit ac ipsum placerat scelerisque eget id justo.  hendrerit. & k
\\
  &     &   &  
\\
\cline{2-4}


 & g & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut elit ac ipsum placerat scelerisque eget id justo. Ut cursus viverra neque, in porta justo facilisis sit amet. Donec vitae libero a diam lobortis ultrices. Vestibulum metus urna, pharetra et cursus quis, eleifend ut dui. Phasellus pellentesque, quam et hendrerit. & p
 \\
 \hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a documented feature:-) hard to do that automatically but `\\\cline{...}\pagebreal\cline{..}`  probably works (you don't say but I assume this is longtable?)

Comment: How you defined table head and foot of table? Please, provide complete document, which we can copy to our computers and compile.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle not longtable because there is some compatibility issue with tabularx.

Comment: Here the code: http://pastebin.com/jf1J9hHu

Comment: Please don't use external links, the question is archived forever and makes no sense if that pastebin goes. it is longtable just called indirectly via ltablex, I'll add to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have what you want incorporating `cline{2-4}` to `\endhead`. I suppose you inserted some empty rows to give vertical padding to cell contents. I made padding it automatic. Also I used the (redefined) `X` column type to make the table full width.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{ >{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}%
  {| >{\hsize=1.1\hsize\columncolor{blue!10}}X|
  >{\hsize=0.55\hsize}X|
  >{\hsize=1.25\hsize\rule{0pt}{4ex}}X <{\mbox{}\rule[-2.5ex]{0pt}{0pt}}|
  >{\hsize=1.1\hsize}X|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{gray!50}\textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} \\%
  \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \hline
  \endhead
  \textbf{Bla bla bla}\par
  \emph{jjjjj}
                               & r & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut elit ac ipsum placerat scelerisque eget id justo. Ut cursus viverra neque, in porta justo facilisis sit amet. Donec vitae libero a diam lobortis ultrices. Vestibulum metus urna, pharetra et cursus quis, eleifend ut dui. Phasellus pellentesque, quam et hendrerit. & d \\
  \cline{2-4}
                               & r & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut elit ac ipsum placerat scelerisque eget id justo. hendrerit. & k
  \\
  \cline{2-4}
                               & g & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut elit ac ipsum placerat scelerisque eget id justo. Ut cursus viverra neque, in porta justo facilisis sit amet. Donec vitae libero a diam lobortis ultrices. Vestibulum metus urna, pharetra et cursus quis, eleifend ut dui. Phasellus pellentesque, quam et hendrerit. & p
  \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]